# Inserts an additional character when i append strings using string builder,why?

Tags: asp.net, stringbuilder

I use the following code,

```
 body.Append("grant_type=password&");
    body.Append("client_id="+clientID +"&");
    body.Append("client_secret="+clientSecret+"&");
    body.Append("username="+username+"&");
    body.Append("password="+password);
    body.Append(security_token);
```

But inserts an additional character '1' between password and security_token. Note that 'body' is a StringBuilder object.

**update**

this issue happens when the password has a number in it.

for example

```
password ="enterinside";
security_token ="1bbssddffgg";
```

then the output comes as "enterinside1bbssddffgg"

but if the password="enterinside999"
     security_token ="1bbssddffgg"
then the output comes as "enterinside1999‏bbssddffgg".

Comment: When I try it, I get the expected "password=enterinside9991bbssddffgg"

Answer (score 0):

you could simple do AppendFormat

```
body.AppendFormat("password={0}1",password);
body.Append(security_token);
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/appendformat

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Khaja Moham if the password is "xyz22" and token is "1shfnhhdtr2kh0",then appended string will be "xyz122shfnhhdtr2kh0".The character '1' is displaced in the appended string.How can solve the problem?

Comment: After appending that would be "xyz221shfnhhdtr2kh0" with your code. If you use appendformat, the way i specified that would result in "xyz2211shfnhhdtr2kh0"

Comment: Khaja Moham Yes, you are correct. The expected output is "xyz221shfnhhdtr2kh0". But the appended string gives "xyz122shfnhhdtr2kh0".I need the exact appended string.

Comment: "xyz122shfnhhdtr2kh0" output is only possible if your password is "xyz" & token is "22shfnhhdtr2kh0" with AppendFormat

Comment: are you sure the output is "enterinside1999‏bbssddffgg" if the password="enterinside999" security_token ="1bbssddffgg"

Comment: `static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var password = "enterinside999";
            var security_token = "1bbssddffgg";
            sb.Append("password=" + password);
            sb.Append(security_token);
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }` output for the above program is this "password=enterinside9991bbssddffgg"